# Android image captured using camera doesn't get saved in specified custom folder on android nougat

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-fileprovider, android-7.1-nougat

I am trying to save an image in a folder named "appFolder"  using android camera.My target sdk is 25.My device is running on android nougat. However,when i click the image using "dispatchTakePictureIntent()". The image doesn't get saved in appFolder.It gets saved in DCIM/camera folder. Why is this happening and how to save this in my custom folder?

```
 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.i("imageCaptutreError", ex.getMessage());

                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                "com.abc.def",
                                photoFile);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                    }
                }
            }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "appFolder");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }
            File tempFile = new File(folder, "temp_image.png");
                    /*new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "appFolder" + File.separator + "temp_image.png");*/

            mCurrentPhotoPath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
            return tempFile;
        }
```

**Provider in Mainifest**

```
   <provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="com.abc.def"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
            </provider>
```

**@xml/file_paths**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="my_images" path="appFolder/" />
    </paths>
```

Answer (score 2):

Partly, it is because you did not call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `Intent`. As it stands, the other app does not have write access to the location identified by your `Uri`.

However, do bear in mind that third-party camera apps have bugs. Ideally, they honor `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Some, however, will not:

- ...because they ignore `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in general, or
- ...because they do not know how to deal with the `content` scheme on the `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (even Google's own camera app had this problem until mid-2016)

FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) shows using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` together with `FileProvider`.

Comment: added the line takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION); ....but wasn't useful

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker: Then the camera app is deciding to store the image where it wants to, regardless of `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. There is nothing much that you can do about this.

Comment: Can i get the path of stored image on activity result and copy it to my desired location?

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker: You can see if the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()` has a `Uri` in it. It is not supposed to. However, if there is a `Uri`, it may point to where the camera app saved the photo.

Comment: intent.getExtras().get("data") this gave me a bitmap ...can i use this?...howver intent.getData() returned null

Comment: instead of saving file in filesystem...can i directly get bitmap or byte array?

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker: "can i use this?" -- yes. That means that the camera app is pretending as though you did not have `EXTRA_OUTPUT` at all, and it is giving you a thumbnail image back. "can i directly get bitmap or byte array?" -- um, the bitmap in `get("data")` already is a bitmap.

Comment: so now since i am getting a bitmap...is it neccessary to save the file?....A bitmap is enough for me...i don't want to randomly save file

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker: Then don't save a file. That is up to you.

Comment: for not saving a file,i should use Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                "com.abc.def",
                                null); instead of Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                "com.abc.def",
                                photoFile);    ?

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker: No. If all you need is a thumbnail, get rid of the `FileProvider` and `EXTRA_OUTPUT` entirely, and just use `get("data")` in `onActivityResult()` to get the thumbnail.

Comment: Note that the *data* bitmap is usually quite small; its official destiny is to provide an onscreen thumbnail for the captured image. Even if on your device you may be satisfied with its quality, you should see how other relevant devices behave.

Comment: @AlexCohn then how can i save my image and how can i get my original image??

Comment: @CommonsWare is there anything i can do to get original image?

Comment: If you choose to rely on the app that fulfills **MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** intent on your device, know that may be *a)* a good preinstalled camera app best tuned for the specific device *b)* a buggy preinstalled camera app that is not fully compliant *c)* a third-party app that the end user installed on her device. You should expect minimum from it, and be prepared for the case when it silently ignores `EXTRA_OUTPUT` you provide. Or, you can build a custom camera capture activity for your app.

Comment: *"how can i get my original image"* - it's not ***your*** image, it's a picture captured by an external application. If it chooses to give you the image Uri, you can try to use it to access the original image.